# PHP Login System

Tags: php, html, sql, authentication, undefined-index

So i am having a slight problem with my PHP login system.When trying to login it continues to say username/password incorrect although it is stored in the database and there is an undefined index.
Login page

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])){
$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]);
$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]);
$password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE username='$user_login'AND       password='$password_login_md5' LIMIT 1");

$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($userCount == 1){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $id = $row["id"];
}
if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["user_login"])){
$_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
header("Location: home.php");
exit();
}
}else{
echo '<div class="echo">Username/Password is incorrect</div>';
exit();
}
}
?>
```

Header page

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die("Couldnt connect");
mysql_select_db("pageslip") or die("Couldnt slect db");
?>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_login'])){
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
else
{
//header("Location: home.php");
}
?>
```

Logout Page

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Home Page

```
<?php
include("header.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["user_login"])){
echo $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
?>
```

I am currently not worrying about the password hash just yet and it would be helpful to stay on topic of the problem and to get a direct solution.

Comment: Why is your header working when you print out spaces before session_start? This could be your problem

Comment: so you only allow `A-Za-z0-9` as your passwords how secure… even if user uses a secure password you reduce its strength…

Comment: How exactly can i configure this

Comment: Please look into using `password_hash`. It's packaged with PHP for a reason.

Comment: Like @Class pointed out, I would suggest you to refrain from using your login system for anything other people are registering for, because they are entrusting their password to you... "never roll out your own crypto"

Comment: Brendan, read about password security and proper hashing here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: there is a great Register & Login tutorial at phpacademy.org

Comment: @brendanOggeri and more thing, give us your form as well please. Thanks have a nice day. And as i am thinking you have same problem its say user does not exist and undefined index?? yah?

Comment: @brendanOggeri read both comment which i posted today, on my solution. Thanks. and do as i said we are going to solve it. read only comment not the solution. I posted them below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note::** I am using mysqli_ instead of mysql_, But dont think mysqli_ automatically secure your applications. You need to learn more.

You did not give the name for the first file, i am assuming its **login.php**, and neither you show us your form so i created my own short form. for you to understand it you can change it according to your need.

The sort form i created is here

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
<!--As i gave the file name login.php, if your file name is different you 
can change it.-->
    Username:<input type="text" name="user_login"><br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password_login"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Now from here your code start**

For **Login.php** (you can change the file name. as you want)

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])){
$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]);
$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]);
//$password_login_md5 = md5($password_login); i removed this line as you say you 
//are not worry about the security, at this time. 
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE username='$user_login'AND password='$password_login' LIMIT 1")or die(mysqli_error($con));

$userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($userCount == 1){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  $id = $row["id"];

  $_SESSION['user_login']=$_POST['user_login'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["user_login"])){
$_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
header("Location: home.php");
exit();
}
}else{
echo '<div class="echo">Username/Password is incorrect</div>';
exit();
}
}
?>
```

**Reason:**its always showing this message that username/password incorrect, is this 
Because that how you coded means your query is not returning any thing. is not because you entered wrong username or password in your form. thats only means you did not execute your query properly.

** Header page.**

```
<?php
$con=  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pageslip') or die(mysqli_error($con));

?>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_login'])){
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
else
{
//header("Location: home.php");
}
?>
```

**Logout page.**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

**Home page.**

```
<?php
include("header.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["user_login"]) ){
echo $_SESSION["user_login"];
}

?>

//**Note: ** I change this line 
//if(isset($_SESSION["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["user_login"])){ 
//to this if(isset($_SESSION["user_login"]) ){
//Means i removed this part && isset($_POST["user_login"]) 
//Reason i am explaining below
```

**Reason::** on the home page you cant access the $_post, variable, Post request are only available for action page like if form action="loging.php" you can not access it on any other page.

In my view you are thinking because you started a session thats mean you can access the post request. not this is not how the session work. in session you can store the value, and can access it on other pages. but not the post request. means it being destroyed after you left the page. and as in your case you are redirecting the user to the home page, thats means there will nothing in the $_post; so thats why i removed it.

To understand it better do two thing in home page, first use **var_dump($_session);**
and check the result it will produce the array, and use **var_dump($_post);** it will give the result like this array(0) { } means there is nothing in the $_post for the homepage.

Hope you get the idea.

**And you got one more problem undefined index.**

This is not the big problem. i am assuming you got this problem in the form section. It simply means you have not defined the index. simple add this on the top of the form like this. **$_post['user_login']="";**

it will go away, repeat this for every undefined index error.

Comment: It didnt work again it still has the same errors.But thank you

Comment: Nope @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: @BrendanOggeri its funny, if you are using the same code it should work. May be the problem is in your database. Can you give us your database structure. Thanks

Comment: <form action="indexlogin.php" method="post">
     <td width="10%" vallign="top">
         <input type="text" name="user_login" size="28" Placeholder="Username"><br>
         <input type="password" name="password_login" size="18" Placeholder="Password"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
     </form> @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: id int (11) AI
email varchar (55)
username varchar (28)
fullname varchar (35)
password varchar (18) @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: @brendanOggeri i think i got your problem, but in order for me to sure, make new file and run this code in that file. <?php

require 'header.php';

$sql="SELECT * FROM users";
$result=  mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
}

Comment: @brendanOggeri than reply me with result on my email arif_suhail_123@yahoo.com, but i think after running this query you will have a idea what you are doing wrong. and if you got the idea dont forget to accept the answer. and if you are still have a problem dont worry we gonna solve this. we are almost there. Thanks bye

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting your Session. You only read it. Because of that, your if expression returns false and the error message is shown.

Comment: if(!isset(sessionxyz) & & postxyz) the ! Negates it and only sets the session variable for users not logged in. In your current code, only already logged in users can log in, obviously not working...

Comment: Is that included in the header or home page?

Comment: @Brendan read through your code and think for yourself, get yourself a paper and write every variable and its changes on it. What has to happen for a user to login?

Comment: Well i mean im not to clear about this because ive only done markup and i just started PHP

Comment: @Brendan then see it as an exercise. If I tell you how your code has to be fixed and also fix it for you, you have learned nothing. I advise using password_hash instead of md5 on a side note...